# Can't log into website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2013

Im trying to create a login form for a website using ms access database. I'm using visual studio 2010 c# and access 2013. For some reason I can't get it to log in. I'm really new to this so any help is appreciated.

DataLayer:

```
public class DataConnector    
{        
    protected OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();        
    public string ErrorMessage = "";

    public DataConnector(string ConnectionString)
    {
        OleDbConnection Connection1 = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        this.DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("", Connection1);
        this.DataAdapter1.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("", Connection1);
    }
    public DataTable DataSelect(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
            DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            DataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
            DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
            ErrorMessage = "";
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            ErrorMessage = err.Message;
            DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public int DataInsert(string query)
    {
        int Result = 0;
        try
        {
            DataAdapter1.InsertCommand.CommandText = query;
            DataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
            Result = DataAdapter1.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
            ErrorMessage = "";
            return Result;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            ErrorMessage = err.Message;
            DataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
            return 0;
        }

    }
    public int DataUpdate(string query)
    {
        return DataInsert(query);
    }
    public int DataDelete(string query)
    {
        return DataInsert(query);
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataLayer.DataConnector dat = new DataLayer.DataConnector("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.O;"+"Data Source='"+Server.MapPath("site_database.accdb")+"'; Persist Security Info=False;");
        DataTable dt = dat.DataSelect("select UserID from tbl_login where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password = '"+ txtPassword.Text +"' ");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("members_area.aspx");
        }
        else
            lblerror.Text = "Login failed";

    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors and I just can't figure it out. When I try to log in it just stays on the default.aspx page.

Comment: If you have no additional information for us, like Exceptions, it is really hard to find out what is going wrong. Please try to put a breakpoint in your btnLogin_Click event if you haven't tried that already. It might help you understand the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem could very well be that `PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL, so if you want to use it as a field name in a query you should surround it in square brackets, e.g.

```
... WHERE Username = ... AND [Password] = ...
```

Note also that you really should be using a parameterized query in case [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) tries to log in.